# Why can't I create func in swift playground?

Tags: swift

I tried here http://swift-lang.org/tryswift/

```
func sayHello(personName: String) -> String {
    let greeting = "Hello, " + personName + "!"
    return greeting
}
```

error message :

Could not compile SwiftScript source: line 3:14: unexpected token: (

Comment: It worked for me try the restart Xcode.

Comment: The Swift playground and compiler are a little fragile at times.

Comment: @Silo you're right restarting seems to make it work

Comment: func greet(name: String, day: String) -> String {
    return "Hello \(name), today is \(day)."
}
greet("Bob", "Tuesday")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong Swift language – the website/online interpreter you're linking to is the site of the Swift Parallel Programming language, which has nothing to do with Apple's Swift language.

Your code works in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

http://swift-lang.org/tryswift/ doesn't look like it's anything to do with Apple Swift. The "try Swift" page you're using is for [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_%28parallel_scripting_language%29), not [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_%28Apple_programming_language%29).

Note that Apple's has the stylised [swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift) in its logo heading downwards; the parallel scripting language Swift is heading upwards :)

To try Apple's Swift in a similar way, you'll need the Xcode 6 beta and a "playground" file.

Answer (score 2):

That is a whole different `Swift` language which has been existing for a while.

The playground for Apple's Swift is available as a Desktop application only at the moment. Follow the links from here - https://developer.apple.com/swift/